# Constraints and optimal table design

Tags: sql, database-design

Here's my design as is

[image: ERD]

I want a constraint that will ensure only (at most) one result of

```
select ID 
  from A a, B b 
 where a.ID = b.PartialKey_Ref_A
       and a.PartCandidateB = 'valueA' 
       and b.PartialKeyB = 'valueB'
```

Incidentally (perhaps changes the optimal design) I want at most one result from

```
select ID 
  from A 
 where PartCandidateA = 'valueA2' 
       and PartCandidateB = 'valueB2'
```

How can I enforce the constraint and optimize the design?

Comment: Does `Key` means that it's a `PRIMARY KEY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that where you write `Key`, you mean Unique or Primary Key. And that `ID` means a surrogate (auto-generated) identifier. With these assumptions, the two tables are in `1:n` relationship and you could change them into:

```
Table A
-------
PartCandidateA
PartCandidateB
ID
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
UNIQUE KEY (PartCandidateA, PartCandidateB)    --- or PRIMARY if you drop the ID
                                               --- this is your second constraint


Table B
-------
PartCandidateA
PartCandidateB
PartialKeyB
PRIMARY KEY (PartCandidateB, PartialKeyB)      --- or UNIQUE
                                               --- this is your first constraint
FOREIGN KEY (PartCandidateA, PartCandidateB)
  REFERENCES A (PartCandidateA, PartCandidateB)
```

---

So, your query to find the `ID` will be written as:

```
SELECT ID 
  FROM A a, B b 
 WHERE a.PartCandidateA = b.PartCandidateA
   AND a.PartCandidateB = b.PartCandidateB
   AND b.PartCandidateB = 'valueA' 
   AND b.PartialKeyB = 'valueB'
```

Comment: +1 this simple design does indeed satisfy the over-complicated spec :)

Comment: Well, I need to look up the ID column from the other candidate key in Table A. I also need to look up ID by PartCandidateB in A and PartialKeyB in B, so I wanted to put a constraint somehow or simplify the design. I can't just take that column out

Comment: When I say other candidate key in Table A, I mean PartCandidateA,PartCandidateB

Comment: Yep, adding the column to Table B, except I think want to reference ID, instead of the candidate key (PartCandA,PartCandB)

Comment: You only need one reference to either a Primary or a Unique Key. So, why do you think you need the `ID` too, in table `B`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I need to add the PartCandidateB column to Table B.
Then I can add the unique constraint on (PartialKeyB,PartCandidateB).
This will increase the DB by sizeof(PartCandidateB)*rows in TableB.
But the constraint will be enforced:)

I don't think this introduces any problems other than the size increase thing

Thanks to everyone

[image]

Comment: The size increase is not a problem at all. The problem is how to enforce that a `B.PartCandidateB` field has the same data with the `A.PartCandidateB` related field.

Comment: I can run the first query on Table B only and the second on Table A as before

Comment: Did you see my edit? I've updated with a query that is equivalent. There is no reason to run a query against one table **only**. That's what Joins are for.

Comment: Oh, youre saying Table B should reference the Key PartCandA,PartCandB so that PartCandB in TableB is actually the same data, but then I would have to query for A.ID on the join like you say.

Comment: @ypercube So I would also have to add PartCandidateA, just like you have in the creates.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply create a unique contraint on those two columns by creating a unique index over them:

```
create unique index ind1 on tablea(PartCandidateA, PartCandidateB);
```

Comment: That's for the second constraint. The first one is related to 2 columns, one from each table.

Comment: So I think, I can NOT make a constraint on tableA(PartCandidateB) AND tableB(PartialKeyB) ? This is what I want for the first constraint

Comment: How do you know that the OP's SQL product supports this syntax or even supports indexes? (perhaps it is not based on contiguous storage on disk at all!) Better IMO to create a `UNIQUE` constraint and if it happens to be the case that the DBMS uses indexes to enforce the constraint then so be it. On an unrelated note, yesterday I lost valuable minutes wondering why SQL Server Management Studio won't give me the DDL for the key I know exists before realising the designer had chosen to create it using `create index`!

Comment: one day when the relational model gets taught properly all over the world again, then perhaps there will no longer be people who know nothing but objects, perhaps database designers will get back to a state where they have the necessary knowledge of fundamentals to do so (and, unlike the days that we live in now, having that knowledge will be prerequisite to becoming a database designer to begin with), and you will no longer lose those valuable minutes ...